# Is there a way that Python can communicate with a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome

Context: I recently realized that YouTube has this new chapter thing feature, I listen to a lot of music mixes and such and those have the song name as chapters, and on linux I print the currently playing YouTube song anyway, so I tought that instead of displaying the name of the mix if I could display the song name in a mix using this new chapter feature.

Question: My question would be, is there any way Python can communicate with a Chrome extension written in JS? Because I made this song name finding extension in JS, so only what it does is extract the name of the song with its Xpath then outputs it with console.log(X). I would need this output inside python where I could work with this given song name.

Using selenium and stuff like this, is not an option I think because those are completely separate from the browser

Comment: Python is also completely separate from the browser

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging

Comment: Thank you, Native messaging solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You can either work on translating your Python code to JS and adding it to the extension, or running a web server built in Python that you can make requests to.